# Why SimpleDateFormat.format() and SimpleDateFormat.parse() are giving different time though setting only one TimeZone?

Tags: java, date, timezone, simpledateformat

I am trying to set the Timezone to the different country's timezone with help of **SimpleDateFormat**. **SimpleDateFormat.format()** returns correct current time of the given Timezone, but **SimpleDateFormat.parse()** returns local current time, I don't know why this is happening.

Here is the my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println("Time1 : " + dateFormat.format(new Date()));
System.out.println("Time2 : " + dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date())));
```

The output is:

```
Time1 : 2013-01-17 21:01:55
Time2 : Fri Jan 18 10:30:55 IST 2013
```

Time1 is the output of "America/Los_Angeles" and Time2 is the output of local (i.e. "Asia/Calcutta").

I just want the current time of given Timezone in UTC Seconds format (ie Seconds since Jan 1, 1970).

Why SimpleDateFormat.format() and SimpleDateFormat.parse() are giving different time though setting only one Timezone?

Comment: Your last line is effectively he same as System.out.println(new Date());

Comment: Means there is no use of SimpleDateFormat.parse()

Comment: Of course there is. Say you have a string representation of a date  in an XML document, or a database, or sone EDI file, you use that method to parse it into a date. That's just one use case.

Comment: Thank you @Perception, it seems format() and parse() have different functionality.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with **Parse**, you command the compiler to understand the given date in specific format. It understands and keep it in its own format and ready to give whatever format you want!

You are getting a output, which is a signal that you input date is parsed successfully. You dont have a control over the format of the date , that the variable is storing.

using format, you can convert the date to any desired format.

Simply
Parse -> Reading ( I may read it in whatever manner and store in whatever manner I want)
Format -> Write ( I will give you in the format you wanted )

Comment: Thank you, for clearing my doubt.
But how can I get the UTC Seconds from different timezone

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Almost all formats are given here!

Answer (score 3):

dateFormat.format() will give you the output in given format and it will change the timezone to the one set in formatter. (eg dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));)

Whereas dateFormat.parse() assumes date is already in mentioned timezone and it will convert the date to your local timezone.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

The terrible old date-time classes are quite confusing, especially in their handling of implicit default time zones. But your mystery is moot, as these terrible old classes were supplanted years ago by modern *java.time* classes.

```
Instant.now()                // Capture current moment in UTC. This class replaces `java.util.Date`. 
.atZone(                     // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region, a time zone.
    ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) 
)                            // Returns a `ZonedDateTime`
.format(
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME
)                            // Returns a String like: `2013-01-17T21:01:55`.
.replace( "T" , " " )        // Replace the `T` in the middle (from the standard ISO 8601 format) with a SPACE.
```

> 2013-01-17 21:01:55

## java.time

The issue is moot as the terrible old date-time classes such as `SimpleDateFormat` have been supplanted by the *java.time*.

## Current moment

The `java.util.Date` class is replaced by `java.time.Instant`. Both represent a moment in UTC, always in UTC. (Despite `Date::toString` lying to you, in applying the JVM’s current default time zone.)

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture current moment in UTC.
```

Adjust into a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Adjust into another time zone.

```
ZoneId zKolkata = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;  // Contemporary time in India. 
ZonedDateTime zdtKolkata = instant.atZone( zKolkata ) ;
```

All three objects (`instant`, `zdt`, & `zdtKolkata`) represent **the very same simultaneous moment**, the same point on the timeline. Only the wall-clock time is different.

## Strings

When generating strings representing date-time values, I recommend always including the offset/zone information unless the context is absolutely crystal-clear. I have seen much confusion in the business world caused by reports where the time frame was ambiguous.

But if you insist, either define your own formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter` class, or use the given formatter [`ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME) and replace the `T` in the middle with a SPACE.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

> 2013-01-17 21:01:55

## Unzoned date-time

Part of the problem is the ambiguity of your string `2013-01-17 21:01:55`. That string lacks any indicator of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Such a value is *not* a moment, is *not* a point on the timeline. For example, 9 PM in India comes several hours sooner than 9 PM in Québec. Without a zone or offset, that string represents only *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

The legacy classes had no such class to represent this kind of value. In the modern classes, we have `LocalDateTime` for this purpose, a non-moment, date and time-of-day without zone/offset.

The *java.time* classes use ISO 8601 standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings. Your input nearly complies. We need only replace the SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( "2013-01-17 21:01:55".replace( "" , "T" ) ) ;
```

If you know for a fact that the intent behind that string was to represent a moment in a particular time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`. For example, if you are certain it represents a moment on most of the west coast of North America, use `America/Los_Angeles`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Los_Angeles" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( z ) ;
```

To adjust from that zone to UTC, extract a `Instant` object. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust from some zone to UTC. Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

dateFormat.parse() in the second println

```
System.out.println("Time2 : " + dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date())));
```

returns Date and Date.toString() returns string representation of the date in `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy` format. See Date.toString() API

Answer (score 0):

With the first line, you are formatting your local date to specific timezone.It will return a string which represents the argument date passed in specific time zone.But parse function is different.It will return a date object represents a number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 12:00 AM, UTC. It does not contain any time zone information.

Comment: Means SimpleDateFormat.parse() nothing to do with TimeZOne.

Comment: @Deepu...Yes.Java date utility is very limited for dealing with timezone calculations, better try joda